# Return different results from a sequelize hook

Tags: node.js, caching, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get tidy up how my caching is working and thus would like to implement it into the hook of my model. This is what I've implemented so far and I can see that it is setting and getting the cache correctly.

```
hooks: {
        beforeFind: function(opts,fn) {
            cache.get(this.getTableName() + ':' + opts.where.id, function(err, result) {
                if (result) {
                    return fn(null, result);
                }

                return fn(null, opts);
            });
        },
        afterFind: function(result, options, fn) {
            cache.set(this.getTableName() + ':' + result.getDataValue('id'), result, function () {
                return fn(null, result);
            });
        },
}
```

The issue is, after the cache hit, it is still performing the database query and returning the result from the database.

Could someone please tell me how to return the result from the cache and not perform the db query in the scenario of a cache hit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at code [findAll](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/421f0f34356a3484b0f26e92e7fd133af6d3f6db/lib/model.js#L691) (because it is calling for all finds). You can see, that it will return Promise, where first executes hooks and in then block there is you query. That's why you can't implement cache in such way. There is a hot discussion in this [issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2508) about how sequelize need to implement plugin system(and cache in particular).

What can you do know? Take a look at this [lib](https://github.com/rfink/sequelize-redis-cache), where Cacher object is implement over models.